# Windows batches in Cygwin with spaces in path and arguments

Tags: bash, batch-file, cmd, cygwin, cygpath

Consider this dummy Windows batch script:

```
echo %1
```

Supposed just to echo to the terminal its *first* argument.
Assume its path in resp. Windows, Cygwin style is:

```
c:\test\win.bat 
/cygdrive/c/test/win.bat
```

From   Cygwin bash:

```
$ c:\test\win.bat  "hello world"
"hello world"
```

So quotes correctly identify a single argument.

But now let us introduce spaces in path:

```
"c:\te st\win.bat" 
/cygdrive/c/te\ st/win.bat
```

Then:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/te\ st/win.bat "hello world"
```

Gives:

```
"C:\te" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The same happens with:

```
$ "/cygdrive/c/te st/win.bat" "hello world"
```

It should be noted this:

```
$ /cygdrive/c/te\ st/win.bat "hello"
hello
```

That is `hello` is now passed to `win.bat` unquoted (and with `"/cygdrive/c/te st/win.bat" "hello"` either).

How can I have spaces both in the path and the argument?

Comment: Why don't you just write a shell (bash) script if you are using cygwin?

Comment: did you try only the folder name which has space under double quotes like this `/cygdrive/c/"te st"/win.bat "hello world"` ?

Comment: @RBH the same with "te st"

Comment: try to cd to this path and add +x parameters to .bat and then run like this: ./win.bat "hello world"

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "echo %~1" > /cygdrive/c/te\ st/win.bat    
$ cat /cygdrive/c/te\ st/win.bat
echo %~1
$ cmd /c $(echo "c:\te st\win.bat"| sed 's/ /^ /g') "aaa bbb"

C:\Users\Me>echo aaa bbb
aaa bbb
```

Comment: Just a recommendation: It's always better to give an explanation to an answer rather than leave a block of code. If the OP is uncertain enough that they ask a question, this likely won't clear their confusion.