# Cygwin: Invoke batch file with argument, output redirection and complex windows paths

Tags: bash, batch-file, cygwin

How do I invoke a batch file from a bash script under Cygwin, with...

- absolute path to the batch file
- batch file argument(s) representing absolute (windows) path(s)
- output redirection into a file at an absolute path

where...

- all paths may contain whitespace and special characters like parentheses
- all paths are initially present only in Unix format within the bash script?

---

I have a windows batch script C:\Program Files (x86)\bin\script.bat, which takes a (windows) path to an input file as argument - example:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo "This is script.bat. The value of the first argument is [%~1]"
```

I want to redirect the output of script.bat into an output file at another absolute path.

On the windows command prompt (cmd.exe), I would invoke the command like this:

```
C:\> "C:\Program Files (x86)\bin\script.bat" "C:\Input Path\input.txt" > "C:\Output Path\output.txt"
output.txt: This is script.bat. The value of the first argument is [C:\Input Path\input.txt].
```

I can omit the double quotes around the script and the redirection target if I apply "batch-style escaping", but that doesn't work for the argument (for some reason):

```
C:\> C:\Program^ Files^ ^(x86^)\bin\script.bat "C:\Input Path\input.txt" > C:\Output^ Path\output.txt
output.txt: This is script.bat. The value of the first argument is [C:\Input Path\input.txt].
```

...but:

```
C:\> C:\Program^ Files^ ^(x86^)\bin\script.bat C:\Input^ Path\input.txt > C:\Output^ Path\output.txt
output.txt: This is script.bat. The value of the first argument is [C:\Input].
```

I can also wrap the command into an additional call to cmd.exe, using additional double quotes around the whole term:

```
C:\> cmd.exe /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\bin\script.bat" "C:\Input Path\input.txt" > "C:\Output Path\output.txt""
output.txt: This is script.bat. The value of the first argument is [C:\Input Path\input.txt].

C:\> cmd.exe /C "C:\Program^ Files^ ^(x86^)\bin\script.bat "C:\Input Path\input.txt" > C:\Output^ Path\output.txt"
output.txt: This is script.bat. The value of the first argument is [C:\Input Path\input.txt].
```

I can also apply the output redirection to the outer cmd.exe instance:

```
C:\> cmd.exe /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\bin\script.bat" "C:\Input Path\input.txt"" > "C:\Output Path\output.txt"
output.txt: This is script.bat. The value of the first argument is [C:\Input Path\input.txt].

C:\> cmd.exe /C "C:\Program^ Files^ ^(x86^)\bin\script.bat "C:\Input Path\input.txt"" > C:\Output^ Path\output.txt
output.txt: This is script.bat. The value of the first argument is [C:\Input Path\input.txt].
```

---

So far so good. But how can I invoke any of the above command lines from a bash script under Cygwin?

All paths initially exist only in Unix format:

```
#!/bin/sh
BIN_UNIX="/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/bin/script.bat"
ARG_UNIX="/cygdrive/c/Input Path/input.txt"
OUT_UNIX="/cygdrive/c/Output Path/output.txt"
```

Note that the file $OUT_UNIX does not exist at the time the script is called (so 'cygpath --dos ...' doesn't work).

I have experimented with dozens of more or less clumsy combinations of Unix / Windows paths (converting with cygpath), no quotes, single quotes, double quotes, no escaping, "bash-style" escaping, "batch-style" escaping, etc. The only working solution I could find depends on an 8.3-style path for the batch script, which eliminates white spaces and special characters:

```
#!/bin/sh
# [...]
BIN_DOS=$( cygpath --dos "${BIN_UNIX}" )
ARG_WIN=$( cygpath --windows "${ARG_UNIX}" )
cmd /C "${BIN_DOS}" "${ARG_WIN}" > "$OUT_UNIX"
```

But there must be a more systematic and robust way to do this, right?

---

Related questions which all don't fully answer my question:

[Why is it that Cygwin can run .bat scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787522/why-is-it-that-cygwin-can-run-bat-scripts?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Windows batches in Cygwin with spaces in path and arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27089992/windows-batches-in-cygwin-with-spaces-in-path-and-arguments)

[correct quoting for cmd.exe for multiple arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891383/correct-quoting-for-cmd-exe-for-multiple-arguments)

[How to Pass Command Line Parameters with space in Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639663/how-to-pass-command-line-parameters-with-space-in-batch-file)

Comment: Where is the Batch file question in this. You want NON WINDOWS answers.

Comment: @Noodles The tricky point is the transition from bash to batch, the quoting/escaping can be really exciting. I spent many hours to examine similar problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
BIN_WIN=$( cygpath --windows "${BIN_UNIX}" )
ARG_WIN=$( cygpath --windows "${ARG_UNIX}" )
OUT_WIN=$( cygpath --windows "${OUT_UNIX}" )
cmd /c CALL "$BIN_WIN" "${ARG_WIN}" > "$OUT_WIN"
```

The important point is the `CALL` in front of your command.

`cmd /c` fails to start a command with spaces inside, because it splits the command even when there are quotes around.

The `cmd /c` would also work without `CALL`, but with additional enclosing quotes.

```
cmd /c "  "C:\Program Files (x86)\bin\script.bat" "args"   "
```

But it seems to be impossible to transfer raw quotes from cygwin to `cmd.exe`, because cygwin translates quotes to `\"`, so the expression becomes

```
cmd /c \"  "C:\Program Files (x86)\bin\script.bat" "args"   \"
```